# JSON get value of a param of a object whose object name is random

Tags: javascript, json, wikipedia-api

I am very new to JSON, have been pestered to get this done.I have to get the value of "extract" as in the given diagram. This diagram is a object diagram of a json. The value 21721040 can be random, thus I do not know the name of the object whose one of the members I seek.

Thus I cannot do something like

```
query.pages.21721040.extract
```

[image]

So how can I get the value of "extract"?

Out of curiosity should the object whose name is a numeral create an error when I try to access one of its members? Or they just work? For example in this case one of the object's name is "-1".

[image]

If I try to access the value "url" after parsing in JS like this:

```
query.pages.-1.imageinfo.0.url
```

Will it throw an error?

Comment: Do you know the id beforehand?

Comment: try `query.pages["-1"].imageinfo[0].url`

Comment: Nope. Can only be known at runtime.

Comment: Is this data coming from Wikipedia API by any chance?

Comment: @Jack Yes it is being fetched from their API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :

```
query.pages[Object.keys(query.pages)[0]].extract
```

Comment: Javascript's indexes for json are mashed up. Can you comment on that, will your method always return the right value?

Comment: It's different than my answer due to Object.keys() returning an actual array and not an object.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't know the property name, you can iterate over the properties on the object yourself:

```
for (var key in query.pages) {
    if (query.pages.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        console.log(query.pages[key].extract);
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can use the relatively modern [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to obtain an array of keys that the object has.

Comment: Is it a property or a child object? From the very limited knowledge I have it looks like an object as it contains key:value pairs and its not itself a key value pair.

Comment: Can it be modified to register only the property containing "extract"? Or I need to check for empty values?

Comment: @AshwinSingh Is *what* a property or child object? I don't think property and child object are mutually exclusive terms.

Comment: @AshwinSingh I don't understand what you mean by "register the property containing 'extract'"; could you clarify?

Comment: I mean log. I am under the impression that your method will log null values for items not containing any "extract" member. Can the loop be done for a simple straight-forward access as there are cases where there can be a lot of keys..

Comment: @AshwinSingh Doesn't each page have an `extract` property then? That doesn't make any sense.

Comment: I got your point. I thought some might not. Haven't seen any examples, but I was just preparing for incase..

Answer (score 1):

try `query.pages["-1"].imageinfo[0].url`. 
actually all the fields can be considered as string. so you can write `query["pages"]["-1"]["imageinfo"]["0"]["url"]`

if you do not know the `key`, use `Object.keys()` to find out the keys associated to that object. this `key` can be any `key` belong to the `object` or the `object` it has been inherited from. to find out only the object's own key user `hasOwnProperty`